# Capture exceptions and handle those in my custom error handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have my custom error handler defined in Global.asax:

```
void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "General";
    routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
    Response.StatusCode = 500;

    if(httpException != null)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        switch(Response.StatusCode)
        {
            case 403:
                routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
                break;
            case 404:
                routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                break;
        }
    }

    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
    errorController.Execute(rc);

}
```

I'm trying to test my error handler by raising an error like this in my service model:

```
if(albums != null)
{
    albums = null;
    ctx.SpotifyAlbums.AddRange(albums);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This raises an exception, but how can I "catch" this exception with my custom error handler?

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a controller with actions that throw specific exceptions.

```
public class ErrorTestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ThrowHttpException(int httpStatusCode)
    {   
        throw new HttpException(httpStatusCode, "Error!");
    }

    public ActionResult ThrowApplicationError()
    {
        Throw new Exception("Boo!");
    }
}
```

Not fancy, but it does the job. And a 404 handler is the easiest to test - just enter a bad url.